# Unable to use any other theme in android studio

Tags: android, themes, rendering, project

I am new to android development and was developing an overflow menu. I had to change the theme of my project to holo.light to make the action bar visible, but when I try to do so following error occurs ;
[image]

After a lot of searching on the internet I realised that only the themes that begin with AppCompat.something.something were working properly. All the rest were not rendered.

Please help.

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>



    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.naveenjain.test7">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you post your styles.xml here..

Comment: I have posted styles and manifest

Comment: @ayusch jain: Which theme would you like to set?

Comment: I would like to use Holo.Light

Comment: I think this layout rendering error but have you test this code on device or emulator ?

Comment: in your xml preview see at the top AppTheme click that and change your theme and in your styles.xml replace with this---> <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

Comment: @ayuschjain: lets continue in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99753/unable-to-use-any-other-theme-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because android studio is not able to render correct theme for this layout.
This is android studio problem. if you run this application it will run successfully. to solve this problem

1. Select Design tab in android studio when you open layout.
   2.Select Theme option from tool bar area  in android studio.
2. A window will appear choose project theme.
3. Your all project theme appear in right side section.
4. Select appropriate theme.

these steps will solve this error.

Comment: There is no design tab. On trying to change the theme from somewhere else, on choosing project themes it only displays appTheme. But this theme does not display the overflow menu that I need to create.

Comment: When you open your layout xml.  you get two mode to design youe layout 1. you can design you layout using coding. 2. or using drag and drop section. the drag and drop section is called design section

Comment: Kk...I thought you were talking about something in the menu bar. Still when i select project theme it only gives me AppCompat themes, but none of the appcompat themes render overflow menu